# How to JSON decode the post in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I'm using `codeigniter` and I have to use `json` encode using `jquery` and when I want to give the data and validate them I have problem.
My code is:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="nNote nFailure hideit"><p>', '</p></div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Parent', 'Parent', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Language', 'Language', 'required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Order', 'Order', 'required|xss_clean');
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
 //do something here
}
```

How should I handle the post request with JSON?

Comment: where is jQuery code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Something that's important to remember around here is that you have to help us help you. The problem with your post is that you posted a PHP block. No jQuery, no JSON, just PHP (and a snippet from within a class at that which renders it worthless). What I would do if I were you is post the JSON output from your PHP snippet, any errors you're getting and what you're trying to do. We can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure what you're asking, but if you want to respond with json, it's really quite simple, PHP makes this easy for us.

```
json_encode(array('jsonKey' => 'jsonValue', 'jsonKey2' => 'jsonValue2'));
```

Just set the appropriate headers and output that using your favorite mechanism (echo, output buffers, etc)

EDIT: If you want to go in the reverse (you're being presented with JSON data in your script)

Just do the following

```
$myGreatAssocArray = json_decode($jsonStringData);
```

Then, you end up with an associate array that you can easily grab data from, as follows:

```
$firstJsonValue = $myGretAssocArray['jsonKey1'];
```

It's really very convenient (and way easier than with say, Java :P )

Keep in mind though, json_decode is not only going to return arrays. If the JSON is malformed, NULL is going to be returned, so if you need to do any conditionals make sure to use !== NULL or something to that affect.

Comment: Giving the basics is a good idea but please mind that he asked about decoding, not encoding.

Comment: Ahh my mistake, I must have misread his question. Post edited in a few.

Comment: @Zarathuztra tnx